# How to avoid Unity Complie all Standard shader variants

Tags: unity-game-engine

When add ***Standard*** Shader to ***Graphics***——**Always Include Shaders**, Unity always stucks in *sharedassets0.asset*. I know it's unity complies shader variants in the background. it's about 60000 variants which make the .apk size is triple bigger than normal size. And it takes a long time(a couple of hours) to build, even if an empty project.If I remove the shader from the list, when I load a model from asset bundle, it will be a pink.Only add Standard to the list, then everything is ok!Is there any way to solve this problem? Please help me!I googled all I can google!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingShaderLoadTime.html

Comment: I have seen this page already! It does't work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Unity 2018.2 added [`IPreprocessShaders`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessShaders.html) which is described at:
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/05/14/stripping-scriptable-shader-variants/ You can review each individual shader keyword combination in IList<`ShaderCompilerData`> and remove ones you are certain you don't need. The this API is not complicated, but standard shader keywords are not well documented. Some of the keyword correspond to enum [`BuiltinShaderDefine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.BuiltinShaderDefine.html) while others are not. I ended up using this preprocessor to remove any `ShaderCompilerData` with `BuiltinShaderDefine.UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1`, `BuiltinShaderDefine.UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2` and `INSTANCING_ON`(This is not in the `BuiltinShaderDefine` enum) turned on since I am certain we didn't use quality settings toggle and instancing.

The Unity Shader Variant Collections works kind of wonky. I ended up using a plugin called "[Shader Control](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/shader-control-74817)" to clean up the mess. But the process is still far from enjoyable since when you remove a keyword there is a chance you break something.

The best solution I could think of is remove all the "Built-in Shader" (Maybe not "Deferred" is you are using Deferred Rendering) and "Always Include Shaders" at the beginning of the project and if someone needs a built-in shader, download "Builit in Shaders" from the Unity Download Archive and import only the one needed back to the project. So that you can:

- Have 100% control over built-in shader
- Only compile shaders you used
- Avoid shader duplication in AssetBundles (If you pack something referencing default imported shaders, the shader will be duplicated for each AssetBundle)

But this "best solution" is certainly more of a hindsight and does not help your current situation though. Give Shader Control a try.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I want to suggest a method that worked for me. I was going to comment but my reputation hasn't reached 50. I would not recommend this as answer but no harm for you in trying I guess.

Instead of including the shaders under **Graphics——Always Include Shaders** I went to **Project Settings -> Player -> Optimization** and included the shaders under **Preloaded Assets**.

I also have doubts if it is the correct way to do so but it solved my problem. I would be glad if anyone could point out what was wrong about it and explain a bit, as I could not find much reference to this method on the Internet.

I have posted a similar question at game dev stack exchange
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/190092/unity-2020-3-what-is-best-practice-to-include-shaders